# Update field in struct-like enum variant

Tags: struct, enums, rust

I am able to use the struct update syntax with a single struct, but I am not able to use it with a struct-like enum variant. Neither can I update a field from a struct-like enum variant with the dot syntax.

For instance:

```
enum Enum {
    Struct {
        field1: i32,
        field2: i32,
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut my_enum = Enum::Struct {
        field1: 1,
        field2: 2,
    };

    my_enum = Enum::Struct {
        field1: 1,
        .. my_enum
    };

    my_enum = match my_enum {
        strct@Enum::Struct { field1, field2 } => Enum::Struct {
            field1: 1,
            .. strct
        },
    };
}
```

Both ways give me an error:

```
functional record update syntax requires a struct
```

This code:

```
my_enum.field1 = 3;
```

gives me the following error:

```
attempted access of field `field1` on type `Enum`, but no field with that name was found
```

How can I update a field from a struct-like enum variant?

Comment: That's not really a "struct within an enum". Such a thing would look like `enum Foo { Variant(StructName) }`. I forget what is the exact name of what you have, but it *might* be an "enum struct" or perhaps a "struct variant enum"?

Comment: Related, but doesn't answer your question, is this recent [blog series](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2015/08/20/virtual-structs-part-3-bringing-enums-and-structs-together/) that talks about bringing the two concepts together in some ways.

Comment: It's called "struct-like enum variant" [according](http://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#enumerations) to the reference, but I think it is usually called just struct variant.

Comment: I found [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/26948) but one person said that (s)he "does not see how this could work". Any idea why this could not work?

Comment: Well, yes, this couldn't work because `strct` is of type `Enum`, not `Enum::Struct`, because `Enum::Struct` is not a type per se. Therefore, even if in this particular case it is always `Enum::Struct`, the compiler can't reason about it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
match my_enum {
    Enum::Struct { ref mut field1, .. } => {
        *field1 = 3;
    }
}
```