# Access fields of enum struct variant wrapped with a tuple struct

Tags: struct, enums, rust

I have an enum with multiple single field tuple struct variants. Each tuple struct field is a different struct. I tried this code:

```
struct Foo { a: i32 }
struct Bar { b: i32 }

enum Foobar {
    Foo(Foo),
    Bar(Bar)
}

impl Foobar {
    fn new_foo() -> Foobar {
        Foobar::Foo(Foo { a: 1 })
    }
    fn new_bar() -> Foobar {
        Foobar::Bar(Bar { b: 2 })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = vec![Foobar::new_foo(), Foobar::new_bar()];
    let mut i = 0;

    while i < x.len() {
        let element = &x[i];
        match element {
            &Foobar::Foo(_) => { x[i].a = 3 },
            &Foobar::Bar(_) => { x[i].b = 4 }
        }
        i += 1
    }
}
```

The compiler says:

> error: attempted access of field `a` on type `Foobar`, but no field with that name was found

I tried the solution found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33043280/update-field-in-struct-like-enum-variant) but it says:

> error: cannot borrow immutable anonymous field as mutable

How can I modify the fields of the content of vector `x`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because your vector and the reference `element` are immutable. Try this:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = vec![Foobar::new_foo(), Foobar::new_bar()];
    let mut i = 0;

    while i < x.len() {
        let element = &mut x[i];
        match *element {
            Foobar::Foo(Foo { ref mut a }) => { *a = 3 },
            Foobar::Bar(Bar { ref mut b }) => { *b = 4 }
        }
        i += 1
    }
}
```