# Get struct from inside tuple variant

Tags: rust, struct, enums, variant

I have a couple structs like this:

```rs
struct Shirt{
  color: Color32;
  description: &str;

  // other fields
}
```

And then an enum with tuple variants that wrap the struct like this:

```
enum Clothes {
  Shirt(Shirt),
  Hoodie(Hoodie),
  Jacket(Jacket),
  Pants(Pants),
}
```

All these structs implement a trait, and for this example, I'll call it `ClothingItem`.

How can I get the `ClothingItem` out of any `Clothes` variant? I can't use `if let` or `match` because that would require making a whole match arm for each variant, and there could be potentially 100+ variants in this enum example. Every member is guaranteed to have a struct with this trait as its tuple member, and there aren't any struct/unit variants in the enum. Every variant is exactly like this.

(Example of what I'm trying to do)

```
let amogus_hoodie = Clothes::Hoodie(ClothingItem {
  color: Color32::Red,
  description: "When the imposter is sus!",
});

println!("The hoodie's color is... {}!", amogus_hoodie.(/* what do I do here? */).color);
```

This isn't a duplicate of [Access fields of enum struct variant wrapped with a tuple struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34145148/access-fields-of-enum-struct-variant-wrapped-with-a-tuple-struct), because that guy was using a `match` statement. I'm looking for a way to do this for any variant without specifically typing it out in a match statement anywhere. Something like `variant.0`, except the compiler doesn't let me do that, even though every variant in the enum has a `0`th element.

Also, something tells me this might be a code smell... am I doing something wrong in terms of data structures? I'm new to Rust and the whole "enum variants are not types" thing.

Comment: It sounds like instead of a type of clothing item owning a clothing item, the clothing item should own of what type it is, i.e. `ClothingItem` should contain a field `kind` or similar that contains an enum `ClothingItemKind` with variants `Shirt`, `Hoodie`, `Jacket`, etc. What you attempt to do is not possible without naming every single variant explicitly at some point.

Comment: Hold on, I forgot to mention an important detail. The `ClothingItem` is actually different for each variant, but all the structs implement one trait in common. Would I still do this? Using this example, how would I do something like `item.zip_up()` or `item.put_up_hood()` if the kind is in a property rather than containing the struct itself?

Comment: If all variants implement a trait, you might be able to use something like [enum-dispatch](https://crates.io/crates/enum_dispatch) to help implement that trait for your enum.

Comment: @kmdreko This looks pretty close to what I'm looking for, I'll try it. There isn't a way to mark comments as answers on here, is there? Thanks.

Comment: Comments cannot be marked as answers. The usual way is to prompt the comment's author to write it as an answer. If they do not comply in a couple of days I'd suggest to write (and accept) the answer yourself, giving proper credit to the "comment above", of course.

Comment: I'd probably mark it as a duplicate of [Is there a way to directly access a field value in an enum struct without pattern matching?](/q/54061281/2189130) since the answers there basically repeat the comments here.

Comment: @kmdreko Yeah, that one looks about right. Surprised I couldn't find it earlier, though... Even when flagging this as duplicate just now, it didn't show up until I typed most of that question's title into the search bar.

Comment: StackOverflow's search is generally pretty poor and only helpful for very specific uses for user or tag filtering and specific keywords or phrases. Searching for *roughly* what you want often doesn't work.